# Ошибка при соединении с MSSQL из PHP

Tags: php, windows, sql-server, сервер, windows-server-2008-r2

Добрый день.

PHP 7, IIS 7.5 Windows Server 2008r2
при попытке подключения к MSSQL возникает ошибка:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\inetpub\путь\connect.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\путь\connect.php on line 4
```

в `php.ini` директива `extension=php_mssql.dll` отсутствует, самого `php.ini` в этом релизе нет, его заменили на `php.ini-development` и `php.ini-production`

Сам скрипт:

```
$serverName = "mssql02\";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {      
     echo "Соединение удалось.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Соединение не удалось, ошибка:";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

то что нет имени сервера, пользователя, пароля и тд это не ошибка, просто убрал специально

PDO загрузил, закинул в папку ext:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
в php конфиге добавил строчку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но оно не хочешь работать

в выводе пхпинфо вообще нет PDO драйверов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в `phpinfo()` видно что расширение есть?

Comment: Не знаю конечно как там на виндах, но может надо нужный `php.ini-*` копирнуть в `php.ini`?

Answer (score 0):

ODBC драйвер в винду установите.

Вот тут куча ссылок куда и что устанавливать

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

Особенно полезные в комментариях (ODBC драйвер)

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Comment: спасибо большое, можно ссылку если не трудно, а то вдругн версия там не та будет или еще что-то

Comment: скачал, поставил та же беда

Comment: Ссылки добавил. По версиям ничего не подскажу. Ставил под windows + php5.6 + apache.